# Effective sample size for test of independence

Tags: chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio

I am interested in applying a test of independence such as chi-square or log-likelihood in the case where the observations are not independent (observations are sequential in time and there is a temporal correlation).

I have read about computing the 'effective sample size' for use in variance estimates of dependent data, and intuitively it seems like the same idea should apply to these tests (since I have fewer indepedent samples than actual samples).

I have struggled to derive anything concrete though. Does anyone have ideas about this or pointers to existing related work?

Comment: It would be helpful to hear a bit more about the nature of your data and the sort of test you wish to carry out; it sounds interesting.

Comment: Well I have two categorial variables that are derived from time series and so have some weak autocorrelation. I would like to do a Chi-square or G-test of independence on them. One option would be to downsample the data, throwing away say every other sample to be sure of independent data, but I found the effective sample size method for variance of time series, and thought something similar could work here. I tried to work through the proof of Wilks theorem to see a way to introduce autocorrelation but I didn't really get anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this would be something standard...that some method for assessing the association between two continuous-valued time series could be adapted for the categorical case, and that it had already been done.

How about just using the $\chi^2$ test statistic and comparing the observed value to values obtained when you shift one of the series relative to the other (cutting it somewhere and rolling the end back to the beginning)?

Comment: That is exactly the sort of thing I plan to do. The problem is the chi2 test assumes independent samples. Here the samples are not independent, because of the weak temporal correlations. So it is unlikely the standard chi-square null distribution is correct and my p-values/inference will be wrong. In Wilk's theorem the sample size N appears a lot so I was wondering if an 'effective sample size' correction could be used.

Comment: @thrope - right, but you either try to adjust the statistic or try to find the relevant null distribution.  My suggestion was to use the same statistic but try to do something like a permutation test.  Alternatively, if you have a reasonable model for the two series (particularly their autocorrelation), you could simulate under the null.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean... I will give it a try thanks.